# Distinguishing Father from Brother

Tags: genetics, dna, statistics

Given the (non-identical) DNA sequences of two men and the knowledge that the second man is either the father, brother, or son of the first man, is the DNA useful in determining which of these three he is?  Even the slightest probabilistic indicator would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will clarify your question a little. We start with two men, Dave and John. We know Dave and John are related, either as brothers, or parent-child. Can we use genetics to work out their relationship?

**If Dave and John are brothers** they will have the same [mtDNA, the DNA in the mitochondria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA), because mitochondria are maternally inherited. They should have the same [Y chromosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_chromosome), because they have the same father (the Y comes from the father, and males have one Y to pass on, therefore they each received the same Y).

**If Dave (John) is John's (Dave's) father**, then they should have different mtDNA because they have different mothers (assuming that Dave (John) didn't have a child with his mother or sister, and that mtDNA is variable within the population). They would have the same Y chromosome, because that is paternally inherited.

If Dave and John have the same X chromosome it would be indicative of the same mother (there is a 50% probability that two male siblings will have the same X chromosome, while the probability of a father and son having the same X chromosome would be determined by variability of the X chromosomes within the population).

For the autosomal part of the genome, each parent carries two copies of each gene. This means that, in each gene, there is the potential for four different alleles, with two of those being passed to the offspring. For example, at gene $A$ the mother may have alleles $A_1$ and $A_2$, while the father has $A_3$ and $A_4$. The offspring receives one copy from each parent, with equal probability. The probability that a son receives $A_3$ from the father is 50%. The probability that a second son receives the same $A_3$ allele is 50%. Therefore, both father-son and brother-brother relationships have a [coefficient of relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_relationship) of 0.5.

**In summary, the mtDNA will liekly be the best indicator, but it is only indicative, it is possible (but highly unlikely in most modern societies) for father and son to share the same mtDNA.**

---

You could, in principle, work out whether Dave is John's son or his father. For example (a *really* over simplified example), look at the diagram below. You first look at Dave's sequence and one chromosome in a pair has the sequence `AAAAAAAAAA` (Red chromosome) while the other has `GGGGGGGGGG` (Yellow chromosome). You then look at John's sequence and find one chromosome with the sequence `TTTTTTTTTT` (Green chromosome) and one with the sequence `AAAAGGGGGG` (Red & Yellow Chromosome). John could have received the `AAAAGGGGGG` chromosome from Dave after Dave's red and yellow chromosome [recombined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination), while it is not possible that John is the father of Dave. John's green chromosome came from his mother.

[image]

Comment: +1 I am not quite aware about this but does Y-chromosome have enough polymorphic loci to differentiate close relatives? Is the variation in Y sufficient for these tests?

Comment: Depends really - a lot of the problems are methodological (sequencing the Y is difficult because of heterochromatin and repeat sequences) - and populations should be highly depleted for variation within, it would depend on the specific population and some regions of the Y generate new variation quickly (again, repeat sequences)... The key to the question is really the mtDNA, that's going to be the best indicator. The Y should be the same in both males regardless of the relationship.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I made some edits to clarify the points.

Comment: Also, perhaps you can add a note on how to differentiate whether an individual, X, is a son or a father of the other individual, Y.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I haven't considered whether this actually possible before, here is something that I think should work in theory

Comment: Another possibility is to look at imprinted loci.

Comment: I think you meant "there is a 100% probability that two male siblings will have the same X chromosome" and that Steve is John, right?

Comment: It's 50% - the mother has two X chromosomes, each will receive one of those with 50% probably that they get the same one. Well spotted on the name.

Comment: OK, I get it now and see why the mtDNA is the better indicator.  By the way, for bonus points, if I had changed brother to "half-brother from the same father" in my original question, is there a method?

Comment: Male half sibs would have the same Y and different mtDNA and X chromosomes - and they'd be related at the autosomal loci with a coefficient of relatedness of 0.25 (differing at the maternally inherited genes inline with population variance, at the paternally inherited genes having 50% probability of identity by descent)